# Is the derivative map a surjection of differentiability classes?

Tags: analysis

It is clear to me from basic calculus that differentiability is a stronger condition than continuity, hence $C^{1}\subset C^{0}$.

But, there is something that has been bothering me recently. I stumbled across the same quandary a few years back, but I can’t seem to remember how I reconciled it…

For simplicity, assume $X$ is an interval and consider the differential map $D:C^{1}(X)\rightarrow C^{0}(X)$.

Clearly D is a function since by definition, given $f\in C^{1}(X)$, it’s derivative exists and is continuous, and also any pair of continuous functions that are the derivative of the same continuously differentiable function, must be equal.

Here’s the thing that is tripping me up…

By the fundamental theorem of calculus, given any continuous function $g\in C^{0}(X)$, shouldn’t we be able to construct a continuously differentiable function in the form of its antiderivative  $f(x)=\int_{a}^{x}g(u)\,du$ on any subinterval $[a,x]\subset X$ since a continuous function is Riemann integrable?

But, this would seem to imply that $D$ Is surjective, which is certainly not the case in general. Otherwise, we would have $C^{1}(X)=C^{0}(X)$, which is not true.

So, where is this line of reasoning incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that there is a surjective map $f$ from a subset $A$ of a set $B$ into $B$ does not imply that $B=A$. For instance, take $f\colon\Bbb N\longrightarrow\Bbb Z$ such that$$f(n)=\begin{cases}\frac{n-1}2&\text{ if $n$ is odd}\\-\frac n2&\text{ if $n$ is even.}\end{cases}$$Then $f$ is surjective, but $\Bbb N\ne\Bbb Z$.

Comment: It does if we already know that B is a subset of A.

Comment: Then what's wrong with my example? Isn't $\Bbb Z$ a subset of $\Bbb R$?

Comment: I apologize, I meant to say, that it does if we already know that A is a subset of B.If a map is a surjection, then the cardinality of the codomain is less than or equal to the cardinality of the domain. $A \subset B$ and $card(A)\geq card(B)$ implies $B \subset A$ and hence $A=B$

Comment: I've edited my answer. What do you think now?

Comment: Note that it is false that $\operatorname{card}(A)\geqslant\operatorname{card}(B)\implies B\subset A$.

Comment: Ok I see what you’re saying. You’re correct.

Comment: If my answer was useful, perhaps that you could mark it as the accepted one.